# Given an adjacency matrix denoting cost between n elements, how do I divide the n elements into k groups?

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, binary-search

Given the cost between n elements where cost[i][j] denotes the cost between elements i and j, we need to divide the n elements into k non empty groups such that if 2 elements belong to the same group, the cost between the pairs become 0. Given the division, let M be the minimum cost of 2 pairs not belonging to the same group. I need to find the maximum possible M. (the division isn't given to us, we need to find the optimal division and then find the maximum possible M)

I thought of sorting all cost[i][j] and then binary searching on it. Let's say we're at position x in the sorted array where the cost is M and it denotes an edge between (i,j). We assume that it's the maximum possible M. So we know that the ith element and the jth element need to be in different groups. Then we bfs from the ith element and add all adjacent elements with cost less than current M. This will be in the current group. We continue bfsing until we run out of elements in this group. Then we move over to our next group and do bfs again from the jth element. If we come across an element that's already in a previous group but has cost less than M with an element from the current group we either return false or try merging the two groups. This is the part that I'm unsure about

an example would be, if n = 3, k = 2 and cost[1][2] = 17,cost[2][3] = 15,cost[1][3] = 16

we can put element 1 in group 1 and element 2 in groups 2 and 3. The maximum M in this case will be min(cost[1][2],cost[1][3]) = 16

This is the best that can be done

Answer (score 0):

If there is no constraint minimal number of elements in a group or that groups have similar number of elements, than it is the best approach to put all elements except `k-1` element in one group and all other groups to consist of one element. To find these `k-1` elements that creates `k-1` groups, sort costs descending and take first `k-1` appeared elements.